# Combo box changes the JTable

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

I've trying to find the answer for some while now. What
I'm trying to do is my combo box is showing 3 items:

1. Students
2. Projects
3. Doctors

Each have their individual tables, so if my combo box
shows students they show the table of students in the `JTable` and so on.

Comment: And what is your problem? Do you know how to add an ActionListener to the combo box to invoke an action when the user selects an item? Do you know how to create a JTable? Start by reading the [Swing tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). There are sections on 1) `How to Use Combo Boxes`, 2) `How to Use Tables` and 3) `How to Write an ActionListener` to get you started with Swing basics.

Comment: Or is your problem with using SQL. Then you can read the [JDBC Database Access](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html) tutorial. Once you read the tutorials you can come back with a specified question detailing your problem. `and so on` - We have no idea what that means. The forum is for asking specific questions for a specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can take help with below example. It does what you are looking for. Though not a perfect way of doing that but I just made few changes to show how it works.

Enjoy :)

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.net.URL;

    public class TableWithComboBox extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
        private boolean DEBUG = true;
        JPanel jPanel2;
        JFrame frame;
        JTable table;
        JComboBox comboBox;

        public TableWithComboBox() {
            super(new GridLayout(2, 0));

            table = new JTable(new MyTableModel());
            table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
            table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

            // Create the scroll pane and add the table to it.
            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

            // Add the scroll pane to this panel.

            String[] options = { "Students", "Doctor" };

            comboBox = new JComboBox(options);
            comboBox.setSelectedIndex(0);
            comboBox.addActionListener(this);

            add(comboBox);
            add(scrollPane);

        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JComboBox cb = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
            String optionName = (String) cb.getSelectedItem();
            if (optionName.equals("Doctor")) {
                table.setModel(new MyTableDoctorModel());
            } else {
                table.setModel(new MyTableModel());
            }
        }

        class MyTableDoctorModel extends AbstractTableModel {

            String[] columnNames = { "Name", "Department", "Hospital", "Experience" };

            Object[][] data = { { "Saira", "Dep1", "XYZ", new Integer(3) },
                    { "Saira", "Dep1", "XYZ", new Integer(3) },
                    { "Saira", "Dep1", "XYZ", new Integer(3) },
                    { "Saira", "Dep1", "XYZ", new Integer(3) },

            };

            public int getColumnCount() {
                return columnNames.length;
            }

            public int getRowCount() {
                return data.length;
            }

            public String getColumnName(int col) {
                return columnNames[col];
            }

            public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
                return data[row][col];
            }

            /*
             * JTable uses this method to determine the default renderer/ editor for
             * each cell. If we didn't implement this method, then the last column
             * would contain text ("true"/"false"), rather than a check box.
             */
            public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
                return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
            }

            /*
             * Don't need to implement this method unless your table's editable.
             */
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
                // Note that the data/cell address is constant,
                // no matter where the cell appears onscreen.
                if (col < 1) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            /*
             * Don't need to implement this method unless your table's data can
             * change.
             */
            public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
                if (DEBUG) {
                    System.out.println("Setting value at " + row + "," + col
                            + " to " + value + " (an instance of "
                            + value.getClass() + ")");
                }

                data[row][col] = value;
                double totalVal = 100.0 + Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(table
                        .getValueAt(0, 4)));
                fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);

            }

        }

        class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

            String[] columnNames = { "Name", "Degree", "Board/University",
                    "Year of Passing", "CGPA", "Part-Time" };

            Object[][] data = {
                    { "Saira", "B.Tech", "VTU", new Integer(2015), new Float(8.33),
                            new Boolean(false) },
                    { "Smaira", "B.Sc", "CBSE", new Integer(2007), new Float(7.77),
                            new Boolean(true) },
                    { "John", "M.tech", "IIT", new Integer(2009), new Float(8.77),
                            new Boolean(false) },
                    { "Jia", "M.Sc", "Thapar", new Integer(2011), new Float(7.21),
                            new Boolean(true) },
                    { "Kerry", "B.Com", "DU", new Integer(2014), new Float(8.92),
                            new Boolean(false) }

            };

            public int getColumnCount() {
                return columnNames.length;
            }

            public int getRowCount() {
                return data.length;
            }

            public String getColumnName(int col) {
                return columnNames[col];
            }

            public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
                return data[row][col];
            }

            /*
             * JTable uses this method to determine the default renderer/ editor for
             * each cell. If we didn't implement this method, then the last column
             * would contain text ("true"/"false"), rather than a check box.
             */
            public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
                return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
            }

            /*
             * Don't need to implement this method unless your table's editable.
             */
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
                // Note that the data/cell address is constant,
                // no matter where the cell appears onscreen.
                if (col < 1) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            /*
             * Don't need to implement this method unless your table's data can
             * change.
             */
            public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
                if (DEBUG) {
                    System.out.println("Setting value at " + row + "," + col
                            + " to " + value + " (an instance of "
                            + value.getClass() + ")");
                }

                data[row][col] = value;
                double totalVal = 100.0 + Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(table
                        .getValueAt(0, 4)));

                if (DEBUG) {
                    System.out.println("New value of data:");
                    printDebugData();
                }
            }

            private void printDebugData() {
                int numRows = getRowCount();
                int numCols = getColumnCount();
                for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
                    System.out.print("    row " + i + ":");
                    for (int j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {
                        System.out.print("  " + data[i][j]);
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }
                System.out.println("--------------------------");
            }
        }

        /**
         * Create the GUI and show it. For thread safety, this method should be
         * invoked from the event-dispatching thread.
         */
        private void createAndShowGUI(TableWithComboBox newContentPane) {
            // Create and set up the window.
            frame = new JFrame("TableDemo");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

            jPanel2 = new JPanel();

            frame.add(jPanel2);

            // Create and set up the content pane.

            frame.add(newContentPane);
            // newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
            // frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

            // Display the window.
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
            // creating and showing this application's GUI.
            javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    TableWithComboBox newContentPane = new TableWithComboBox();
                    newContentPane.createAndShowGUI(newContentPane);

                }
            });
        }

    }
```